# Alternatives for queue:work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Because queue:work --daemon works infinitely and can consume more memory with time, I want to know are there any alternatives for the builtin Laravel workers?

Basically I'm talking about a Redis driver.
Of course I could consume a Job from a queue with Python for example, and deserialize and understand what to do.

I know about soft restarts for queues (artisan queue:restart) with supervisor. It allows me to free php's consumed memory.

My main problem is: each worker might consume as much as 200 MB memory right now because every worker loads the entire framework. Are there any lightweight ready-to-use alternatives?

Comment: 200 MB memory usage sounds excessive, and you shouldn't see more memory used over time unless you've got a memory leak of some sort.

Comment: I've tried to debug it with xdebug, but it gives a lot of lines with function calls and uses too much disk space to store log for more than 10 minutes.

Comment: The issue is that you're not handling clean up yourself of your job when it's done, thus leaving your work in-memory.

Comment: Post your worker code... maybe we can give you some pointers...

Comment: Workers are quite big and there are many of them.
For example, during one run worker has to make multiple http requests, where every request can return 1-3 MB of raw data, which becomes 3-5 MB of array data. And there are many such examples.

Comment: If You code does work with fat objects so try to `unset($SomeObject)` at the end of overall operation and call `gc_collect_cycles`. I'm using Console/Commands with inifinite while loop with pulling job from queue manager and I've no such issue and I don't do manual cleanup. So I think You better share with us that work item that You handle. Maybe we can find possible leaks